# How to extend this navigation bar off the page?

Tags: html, css

I have a css navigation bar I would like to extend off of both sides of my webpage. Right now it has a very small width and it seems like no matter how much I play with the ratio's nothing is changing. Can anybody help me with this? I'm rather new to web design. I'll post both my CSS and HTML

CSS:

```
/* Links */

.menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 14px;
    margin: 6px 0;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;

    border-left: 1px solid #4075a6;
    border-right: 1px solid #4075a6;

    font-family: Archer,Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: light;
    font-size: 13px;

    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.6);

    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
.menu li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }

.menu li:hover > a { color: #b8ccdc; }

/* Sub Menu */

.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #195892;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    width: 101px;
}

.menu li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }

.menu ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;

    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul li {
    height: 36px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li a {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0;

    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #353539;
}

.menu ul li:last-child a {
    border: none;
    color: #195892;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Developements</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Condominiums</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="documents">Documents</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="messages">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="signout">Sign Out</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Video Tours</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact </a></li>
</ul>
<!-- end .menu -->
```

Comment: not sure about what you want. Add some example or try to recreate the the problem on jsFiddle for example, also looking at 100 lines of css is a bit hard. Place only the css you think must work, like the css for the menu container.

Comment: I'm not really sure what part of the CSS to post because I don't know which part I need to change to extend the width of the box.

Comment: I still don't get it. What box? When I put your code on jsFiddle I see almost nothing, but what I see is that the outer menu box has full width: http://jsfiddle.net/jSdv3/

Comment: What I needed to do was set the width of my .menu to 100% and it worked, however I'm trying to get it to bleed off the edges of the webpage. Do you know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a width on the UL to your desired width. I think 100% would work for you since that will go from edge to edge of the container it's wrapped in.

I recommend placing background colors on the UL and LIs so that you can easily see where they begin and end, then remove once you get them positioned where you'd like.

Comment: Thank you! I actually got it to work, however it isn't bleed off the edges of the page, is there a quick solution to this?

Comment: Do you have a link? How will anyone know if it goes outside of the page unless they can scroll? You could put a large width on it instead of 100% to extend however many pixels you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change my .menu to 100% width and add position: absolute; right: 0; left: 0; and that worked perfectly.